# Inserting records in custom object on clicking SAVE in Bootstrap

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, popup, bootstrap

I am using a Bootstrap modal to create a popup where the user can enter details. The popup has two buttons SAVE and CANCEL.

The popup is a custom VF page wherein I have included the Bootstrap libraries.

I am not able to save records in my custom object from the popup. Please guide me as to how should I go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Visualforce remoting to save records created via bootstrap.  When the user clicks the save button, I pick up the details from the various input fields in the modal dialog and execute a remote method that carries out the insert.  In this example I have two inputs with the ids of 'subj' and 'desc'.  Clicking the save button in the modal executes my saverec javascript:

```
  function saveRec()
  {
    var subj=$('#subject').val();
    var desc=$('#desc').val();

    MyCtrl.insertRec(subj, desc, recInserted, {escape: false})
  }

  function recInserted(result, event)
  {
    if ( (!event) || (event.status) ) 
    {
      if (result=='SUCCESS')
      {
        alert("Record inserted");    
      }
      else
      {
        alert('Error ' + result);
      }
    }
    else if (event.type === 'exception')
    {
        alert('Error ' + result);
    }
  }
```

Then in my controller:

```
public static String upsertRec(String subj, String descrip)
{
    String result='SUCCESS';
    try
    {
        My_Sobject__c sobj=new My_Sobject__c(Subject__c=subj, Description__c=descrip);
        insert tk;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result=ex.getMessage();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton Bob! I too used Remote action to save the records. They are now getting saved successfully :)